# c++ Sum, Average, Largest, Smallest validation issue

Tags: visual-c++

So this program calculates and prints the largest, smallest, average, and sum of the sequence a user enters. My only problem that I have found is that when a symbol is entered, it outputs it is wrong, but still ""adds" it's ascii code to the sum, messing up the results. Also, if someone else a number and letter such as 1361351P, it still reads it. Any help is appreciated.

```
/** C2.cpp
      * Test #2 Problem C2
      * Robert Uhde
      * This program calculates and prints the largest, smallest, average, 
      * and sum of a sequence of numbers the user enters.
      */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Extreme constants to find min/max
const double MAX = 1.7976931348623157e+308;
const double MIN = 2.2250738585072014e-308;


// Create generic variable T for prototype
template <class T>
// Prototype dataSet that with request inputs and calculate sum, average, largest and smallest numbers.
T dataSet(T &sum, T &largest, T &smallest, T avg);

int main(){
    // Intro to program
    cout << "This program calculates and prints the largest, smallest,"
         << endl << "average, and sum of a sequence of numbers the user enters." << endl << endl;
    // defined used variables in longest double format to include as many types as possible with largest range
    double avg = 0, sum = 0, max, min;
    // Call dataSet which returns avg and return references
    avg = dataSet(sum, max, min, avg);
    // Output four variables
    cout << endl << "The largest of the sequence you entered is: " << max << endl;
    cout << "The smallest of the sequence you entered is: " << min << endl;
    cout << "The sum of the sequence you entered is: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "The average of the sequence you entered is: " << avg << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Create generic variable T for dataSet
template <class T>
T dataSet(T &sum, T &max, T &min, T avg){
    T num;
    min = MAX, max = MIN;
    // count number of valid numbers
    int count = 0;
    // Repeat this loop until ^Z
    do{
        cout << "Enter a sequence of numbers: (^Z to quit) ";
        cin >> num;
        // if valid, then increment count by 1, add to sum, find out if it's new max or min
        if(cin.good() && (typeid(num) == typeid(int) || typeid(num) == typeid(double))){
            count++;
            if(num > max)
                max = num;
            sum += num;
            if(num < min)
                min = num;
        }
        // if user enters ^Z break out
        else if(cin.eof())
            break;
        // If there is some sort of type error, print so and clear to request again
        else{
            cout << "Error. Try Again.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(80, '\n');
        }
    }while(true);

    // Calculate average and then return
    avg = sum / count;
    return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditioning check needs some more work. I would use more specific condition checkings such as isalpha or isdigit which are part of the  since these condition checks below are not good enough

```
    if(cin.good() && (typeid(num) == typeid(int) || typeid(num) == typeid(double)))
```

Best of luck!